# 301 Re-direct for vanity url

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect

Stumped with this one...I've got a case where we are doing something very similar to how a site like bitly would opperate.

We've got a vanity URL, say its "myurl.com/randompagename". We own the "myurl.com" but there is nothing called "randompagename" on the server. I initially suggested creating a "randompagename" and putting a JS redirect script in.

```
<script>
  window.location.replace("http://anothersite.com/mynewpage");
</script>
```

Unfortunately I'm told with our hosting we don't have the ability to create pages or add scripts (sounds odd to me).

So now i'm wondering if I have no way of physically creating an end destination for the original page to house the redirect then how do I achieve this?

Would the user not just wind up on a 404 page because the vanity URL doesn't actually exist?

**Edit**
Does anyone know how a site like Bitly does their re-directions? That might help me better understand plausible solutions for this.

Comment: It all depends on what you can do on the server. If you can't set up redirects nor create pages, you're screwed. You'd have to talk to the server admin to see what is possible. `Would the user not just wind up on a 404 page because the vanity URL doesn't actually exist?` probably - you should be able to try that out right away, though?

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for the response - that's what I was afraid of, our IT manager showed me some GUI that he has been provided with but it only takes input for the origin url and the destination url. Which again I think unless the origin page actually exists won't work.

Comment: `Which again I think unless the origin page actually exists won't work.` Are you sure about that, have you tried?

Comment: `Does anyone know how a site like Bitly does their re-directions?` I don't think knowing that will help you here...

Comment: Not yet - waiting for a meeting to go over potential solutions but all the higher ups seems convinced it won't work. I don't have credentials to login and try yet so i'm a little in the dark as well

Comment: A tool that allows creating redirections only for existing pages on a server on which you can't *create* pages doesn't seem to make much sense, so my suspicion is that GUI is how you're supposed to set up the redirection.

Comment: You would need to use modrewrite which is done all the time. It will handle non existent directories. I've done this my self to use /randomstring to the actual video URL. It's not hard.

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 `Not yet - waiting for a meeting to go over potential solutions but all the higher ups seems convinced it won't work. I don't have credentials to login and try yet so i'm a little in the dark as well`. That's why they're managers and not engineers. LOL It can be done with modrewrite and a server side language

Comment: @PanamaJack but how do you use mod_rewrite (or anything else) on a server you can't create files on?